# Step Back to previous line in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#, debugger

Is there any way to step back to previous line in Visual Studio Code while debugging c# ,  just like drag to previous code or any line in visual studio 17 or 19 in windows?

Comment: Were you asking about the "rewind execution" type feature, which is fairly new?  Or simply the ability to change the next instruction and continue execution from a different line, like a "debugger goto"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
[vscode-debug-specs for C#](https://74th.github.io/vscode-debug-specs/csharp/)
do not specify "Step Back" as one of the options.
This is reserved for
[Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/step-back-while-debugging-with-intellitrace/).

[image]

Comment: Any debugger available in vscode marketplace that have stepback

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of.

Answer (score -1):

You can do step-back to previous line in VS code via the use of new Step Backward icon while debugging your code with IntelliTrace Debugging.

First you need to Enable IntelliTrace Debugging feature in your Visual studio code. for do this follow below step

Step 1: Go to Tools > Options > IntelliTrace > General > IntelliTrace events and snapshots

Now you can go previous line while debugging with the help of step backward icon.